# Mongo scrip how we can fetch from two different database collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

how we can retrieve the data, if we have 2 database say 1db and 2db, in 1db we have 'user' collection which include some personal data like firstName, lastName, rollNumber in that we have some duplicate rollNumber user are present and in db 2 we have 'trip' collection, where we have rollNumber, dateOfTravel, source,destination etc..which were created by respective rollNumber now how we can fetch the data which is having duplicate user detail from db 1 and respective trip which is created by that rollNumber also.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from two or more collection use aggregate method using`$lookup`.

```
db.test.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:"test1",localField:"user_id",foreignField:"emp_id",as:"data"}}]).pretty();
```

Here `test` is 1st collection, `test1` is 2nd collection and `user_id` and `emp_id` are join keys from respective collections. And we will get result data in data key as the result.

[This blog](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction) contains a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: The question is about two database, not two collections